# eBPF program, how to obtain net_device from tc through __sk_buff?

Tags: tc, ebpf

eBPF program, how to obtain `net_device` from `tc` through `__sk_buff`?

```
u32 ifindex = skb->ifindex
```

I can get the `ifindex`, but how do I convert it to the `net_device` structure?